# When I export a animated blender model as GLTF into three.js it stretches out

Tags: animation, vertex-groups, gltf

when I animate a blender model with bones

[image]

It runs fine in blender, I export it like so

[image]

and then, this happens

[image]

Any help appreciated.

Link to the GLB https://www.mediafire.com/file/wrubnxlgf6f6pu1/woman.glb/file Link to the .blend (2.8) http://www.mediafire.com/file/azlx6audmcyska9/woman.blend/file

Comment: Try checking `Always sample animations`, does that do something better?  It will be the default setting in Blender 2.81's glTF exporter.

Comment: I did, now even when I try export a simple butterfly animation, all my exported animations seem to distort, some worse than others

Comment: Could you file an issue on the exporter? See https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been recent development done with blenders gltf exporter, so try exporting with a current development build of blender, you can get a [daily build](https://builder.blender.org/download/) or go to [GraphicAll](https://blender.community/c/graphicall/) if you don't want to [compile yourself](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender).

Using a recent build (week old) I can export your blend file to gltf and do not see the issue when importing back into blender, which I do see when importing your sample glb file. Using [sandbox.babylon.js](https://sandbox.babylonjs.com/) also shows the new export to work.

Another thing to try is to [apply the transformations](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/clear_apply.html#apply) to the armature and mesh, the two in your blend file do not have the same location. When the two are moved separately you can see a similar distortion, try it by moving the mesh object in blender separate to the armature.